# How to structure domain model when using NHibernate Search/Lucene

Tags: nhibernate, lucene.net, nhibernate-search

I am messing around with NHibernate Search and Lucene to create a searchable index of legal entities. My domain model looks somewhat like this:

```
[Indexed]
public abstract class LegalEntity : AggregateRoot
{
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Person : LegalEntity
{
    public virtual string FirstNames { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Company: LegalEntity
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Address : Component
{
    public virtual string Street { get; set; }
    public virtual string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    // etc...
}
```

As the subclassing implies, `LegalEntity` is an NHibernate entity specialized as `Person` and `Company`, and `Address` is an NHibernate component.

Now, how would I best go about creating a really Google-like fuzzy search that includes all the fields of a `LegalEntity`, including those inside the `Address` component?

My first idea was to implement an `AddressFieldBridge` to help in bringing in the fields of the `Address` component, and then just throw in `[Field]` on all the fields, but then I could not find a way to construct a `FuzzyQuery` as a conjuntion between multiple search terms.

My next idea was to create an abstract property tagged with `[Field]` on `LegalEntity`, like so:

```
    [Field(Index.Tokenized)]
    public abstract string SearchableText { get; }
```

and then have `Person` and `Company` return texts that combine names and all the fields from the `Address` component into one string, which would then be tokenized and indexed by Lucene.

That, however, made me feel kind of icky.

I would like to learn the best and least intrusive (from a domain model perspective) way to accomplish this task - any suggestions are appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485979/how-to-integrate-nhibernate-with-lucene-net).

[Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39068/andrey-shchekin) created patch to specify lucene stuff outside. Syntax ain't uber clean (maybe there's some progress done on this, haven't checked), but i guess it gets job done.